# How to pass value from a method of one class to the method of other class. Which is used in some other method?

Tags: java

I am trying to pass value from a method of one class to the method of other class. Which is used in some other method .... All classes are in different files but are in same package. Is this possible by inheritance(But all classes are imported) or anything else ... Can't pass value to `hereToUse()` directly... trying to simplifying the code so writing a dummy code

Here is a dummy code ...( Ignore some basic mistakes it is a dummy code ... important is to access the value in `hereToUse()` ) . Thanks in advance ..

A.java >>>>>>

```
class A{
   public String name;  // can't pass value here.... It must be Null
   public void start(){
       B obj = new B();
       name = obj.getValueFrom("XYZ");
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
       A objA = new A();
       objA.start();
   }
 }
```

B.java >>>>

```
class B{
       public String nameB;  // can't pass value here.... It must be Null
       public String getValueFrom(String name){
           nameB = name;
           return nameB;
       }

       public void hereToUse(){
           //System.out.println(getValueFrom("something"));
           //Here i need a value "XYZ" ...
       }
     }
```

We can call `start()` only once ... `hereToUse()` is called by some other class ...
 Is this possible ?? ... i'm new in java ... Kindly help me to sort out this problem 
 Give me some explanation also.
Output is : null
Expected output is XYZ ...

Comment: whats the problem with code.

Comment: Question is updated .... getting null value

Comment: where you are calling `hereToUse()`.

Comment: Please pass parameter to getValueFrom('test') which is in hereToUse() method

Comment: Is the console actually printing `null`, or is the console empty? Because I don't see any place where you are printing anything other than the `hereToUse` method, which is not being called.

Comment: it is called by some other class ...It is a simple method call.. so not mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are trying to call a member function from a static context. Trying to do so will result in a compile-time error. The `this` keyword only exists in a non-static context. I believe you want your `main` method to look something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    A aInstance = new A();
    aInstance.start();
    System.out.println(aInstance.name);
}
```

On the first line in `main`, we create a new instance of `A`. Then we call the start method, and finally print `name` to the console.

Comment: no ... i don't want to print it from `main()` ... As mentioned in the question `hereToUse()` is called by some other class